# How can I do async await in the repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have code that is long running i/o bound perfect for async/await . I am doing the repository pattern and can not figure out how to do await in the controller as I'm getting an **object does not contain awaiter method** on this code

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
     {
    private ImainRepository _helper = null;

    public HomeController()
    {
        this._helper = new MainRepository();
    }
   public async Task<string> Aboutt()
    {
       // Here I get the error
       object main = await _helper.Top_Five() ?? null;
        if(main != null)
        {
            return main.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

The method that I am implementing works fine as you can see below. I get data out of the database and return it in string format. What I would like is to find a way to make 
  **object main = await _helper.Top_Five() ?? null;** await otherwise I would be mixing async with synchronous code. Any suggestions would be great ...

```
    public async Task<string> Top_Five()
    {
        try
        {

            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Config"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string Results = null;
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from streams limit 15)t", conn);


                using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        Results = reader.GetString(0);
                    }

                    return  Results;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Log it here
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What version of .NET framework do you have your project configured to use?  Pretty sure it has to be >= 4.5

Comment: Yes it is actually Asp.Net Core RC2

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
object main = (await _helper.Top_Five()) ?? null;
```

Notice the extra `(` and `)` since you need to await the method and then check for `null`.

Comment: I just tried that but it is still giving of that error

Comment: The parenthesis won't help anything, that's already how the compiler understands that expression.

Comment: @svick Not sure what your working with but that has given me errors quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that Top_Five returns `null` or a `string`, the code is unnecessary:

```
object main = await _helper.Top_Five() ?? null;
```

Instead, do the following:

```
var main = await _helper.Top_Five(); // the "awaiter" completes now
return main; // returns a string or null like in your example
```

Comment: That's still redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of the `null` coalesce operator on the `Task` method. You need to handle that differently, consider the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ImainRepository _helper = null;

    public HomeController()
    {
        this._helper = new MainRepository();
    }

    public async Task<string> Aboutt()
    {
        string main = await _helper.Top_Five();
        return main;
    }
}
```

Notice that when you `await` is all you need as you're returning as `string`, so declare it as a `string` - not an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire method is accomplishing nothing.  `?? null` replaces null with null and anything else with itself.  And that's your only transformation of the result, so you can just write:

```
public Task<string> Aboutt()
{
        return _helper.Top_Five();
}
```